# Select the count of distinct data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that will count how many times id('id_avocat') appear. I want to select the id_avocat where id appears just 1 time;

This is my query :

```
   SELECT id_avocat a, COUNT(*) asd ,`planificare` FROM `generare_liste` WHERE `planificare`="instantelor" AND  asd <2   GROUP BY a ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I'm getting this error: `Unknown column 'asd' in 'where clause'` ,but if I use the 'asd' just in select ,not in where clause,I'm not getting any error.

How can I select just the id `Where count(*) is smaller that 2` ?

Comment: Do you want to select second smallest from a table

Comment: No,select the id where count is smaller than 2

Comment: The `WHERE` condition is executed before the `SELECT`, so the alias are not know and cannot be used

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id_avocat, COUNT(*) asd ,`planificare` 
FROM `generare_liste` 
WHERE `planificare`="instantelor" 
GROUP BY a 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

BTW -- what is column `a` in your `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

let assume your table structure from your question..

```
    ID_AVOCAT   ASD     PLANIFICARE     A
    1           3       instantelor     a
    2           0       instantelor     c
    3           1       instantelor     b
    4           3       instantelor     b
    6           2       instantelor     b
```

then your query must be like..

```
SELECT id_avocat,
   asd ,
  `planificare`
from `GENERARE_LISTE`
group by a
having count(*) < 3
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2907a/3)**